# Disable GridView Item click completely

Tags: android, gridview, onclick, android-cardview

First I have a `GridView` inside a `CardView`.
The `GridView` is only for showing data, Items are not clickable. And each `CardView` has a click event to go to detail `Activity`.

My problem is that when user clicks on `GridView`, it doesn't go to detail `Activity`.

My `CardView` code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/card_view_geo"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/horizontal_space_medium"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/horizontal_space_small"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_gravity="center"
cardUseCompatPadding="true"
cardElevation="3dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/vertical_space_small"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/vertical_space_medium"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/horizontal_space_medium"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/horizontal_space_medium"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_geo_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/vertical_space_small"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size"
        android:text="My Geo"/>

    <br.com.hbsis.indicadores.util.view.WrapContentGridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/grid_view_indicators"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="@dimen/grid_view_column_width"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/grid_view_spacing"
        android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/grid_view_spacing"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post some code

Comment: android:clickable="false"  try to add this to the gridview

Comment: Thanks @Robbert, but it doesn't work.

I've tried this things too:
    android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

Comment: @EricCasteloBrancoMesquita Did you try it on every object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a friend of mine helped me with the solution.

We've created a custom `Gridview` and overrided `onTouchEvent` method.

```
public class CustomGridView extends GridView {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }
}
```